# openssl connect fails for some websites

Tags: ssl, openssl, squid

I'm having some problems getting openssl to consistently connect to some websites.  pnc.com seems to have the problem almost every time.  When I run the following command:

```
openssl s_client -bugs -msg -debug -connect www.pnc.com:443
```

The first time I will always get the following response:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write to 0x1095fa0 [0x11362d0] (112 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

If I run it a couple more times it will successfully connect and I can run a GET for the specific web site I'm looking for, but the connect never works on the first try.  I've seen several posts with similar issues that have been solved by specifying SSLv3, or using the no_tls1_2 option, but neither of those have worked in this case.  I have tried this from both a centOS box as well as my macbook, and using both openssl 1.0.0 and 1.0.1e.

I chased the problem to openSSL after initially suspecting it was the ssl_bump from my squid install.  All I really need is for the webpage to open properly through the squid ssl_bump, so if I could get openSSL to connect properly the first time, or keep retrying until it was successful, or get squid to keep trying until the connection is established, I'd consider it working.

Has anyone else had this problem and found a solution for it?

Comment: This looks like a problem with the web site itself. It just makes a TCP reset after receiving the client hello - and sometimes with the same client hello it does a successful handshake. Could be yet another broken load balancer or IDS.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I agree, it looks like the problem is with the website, but is there a way to make openssl automatically retry until it gets a successful connect? The browser seems to handle the resets just fine when I'm not proxied. It's not until I'm connecting through squid (and therefore openssl) that there's a problem.

Comment: No, openssl does not automatic retries or downgrades, I would also not expect it from a library. And s_client is just a diagnostic tool, so you better see the problems instead of automatically working around them.